# How to get rid of ssh bandwidth limit?

Tags: ssh, arch-linux, openssh, limit, bandwidth

I was playing around with a server I set up myself, running archlinux, and when I tried to retrieve files from it, using scp or rsync, I noticed the download speed was abnormally low, being capped at around 1.1MiB/s, when I didn't met any trouble sending files at 120MiB/s. (I also was able to download files using http at 70 MiB/s)

I then did the following experiment:

```
LOCAL: $ ssh login@host
REMOTE: $ cat HUGE_FILE
```

Result: The content of the file is displayed in the terminal, the download speed is about 15MiB/s

```
LOCAL: $ ssh login@host "cat HUGE_FILE"
```

Result: The content of the file is also displayed in the terminal, but the download speed is only 1.1MiB/s

(Edit: `ssh -t login@host "cat HUGE_FILE"` gives the same result)

It seems there is a specific limit when launching directly a single command, but not in a regular session. I searched all I could but couldn't find some config file enabling such a limit.

So I would be thankful if anyone could advice me on the source of this problem and how to solve it.

Comment: `ssh` server need to encrypt and the client to decrypt. If you don't need encryption, use `netcat` or `socat`: web sockets.

Comment: You might not hit any network limit but are limited by the terminal. Printing characters in the terminal is really slow. If you don't print the file in the terminal but redirect the output in a file, the transfer should be faster.

Comment: @GillesQuénot How could ssh encryption explain the difference in both test cases, which both use ssh ? Netcat could work but its usage would be bothersome, compared to (e.g.) rsync

Comment: @rathier I know there is a limit caused by the display in terminal (max 15MiB/s in terminal, but I got 70MiB/s when using http), but that doesn't explain the difference between the test cases, which both imply displaying the file in the terminal

Comment: compare with `ssh -t login@host "cat HUGE_FILE"`

Comment: @A.B I get the same speed limit at 1.1MiB/s with -t

Comment: Ah sorry, read it in the wrong direction (so this doesn't help).

Comment: Read @rathier comment

Comment: @GillesQuénot I already answered it, the terminal limit cannot explain a x15 difference in two test cases which (and this doesn't seem to be clear enough) **both** imply displaying the file in terminal. That speed limit at 1.1MiB/s is the exact same that is met when using scp or rsync, which don't imply displaying anything in the terminal

Comment: How exactly do you measure throughput?

Answer (score 0):

check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20244585/how-does-scp-differ-from-rsync

- first rule out variability

  - make a simple `test.tar` file of something < 25% of RAM, for example a ~2gb test.tar if you have 16gb of RAM.  Doing too small a single file won't take long enough to copy to give confident results.  Too large a file will fall out of being in RAM and then disk i/o will become relevant which is bad
  - use `scp`
  - do not use the speed result of the first copy, especially after a clean boot, as time for it being read from disk is involved.  Do 3 or more copies to ensure disk cache is in play and your `test.tar` is within RAM
  - keep it simple... *I was playing around with a server I set up myself*... so make one single `test.tar` file of appropriate size and only do `scp` and use the speed that reports.
  - u can do `mount -t tmpfs -o size=8g tmpfs /ramdisk` to create a *ramdisk* and put your `test.tar` in there and copy to/from that *ramdisk* location to help rule out disk i/o.
  - also maybe try putting linux into runlevel 3 *multi-user.target* to reduce background processes that could be running, where the cpu is busy doing other things vs focusing on the `scp`.  However I have never had this problem being in runlevel 5 *graphical.target* at least with RHEL/CentOS/Rocky.
- there is no inherently imposed SSH bandwidth limit, and using a *modern* cpu having the instruction set and whatnot that takes care of encryption processing at that hardware level (I foget the vocabulary at the moment) the encryption overhead is nearly nil and not affecting copy speed certainly not with `scp`.
- you can adjust the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file with regards to `Ciphers` and `Macs`, I noticed a significant difference in `scp` copy speeds but this was on 200gbps infiniband observing like 400 MB/s vs 700 MB/s and 1.0GB/s in RHEL 7.9.  On a 1gbps wired LAN, I do not think you will notice a difference.  And in RHEL 8.9 I notice the `Ciphers` and `MACs` is no longer present in `sshd_config` I believe there is now a different method to apply those.
- you mentioned `MiB/s`; I don't necessary understand that context.  I only know using `scp` reports `MB/s` in the bottom of the window, as well as using samba that the popup in windows10 both show copy speed in `MB/s` and on a wired 1gbps LAN/WAN I have never gotten about 112-113 MB/s, which I consider the max based on 1gbps = 1000 mbit/s / 8 bitperbyte = 125 MB/s then figure 10% reduction for whatever overhead = ~112MB/s.
- What causes the reduction in transfer speed below a constant 112 MB/sec, which I get over X minutes doing a single 400+ GB tar file, can be any number of things; this is on a server having 768gb RAM by the way with enterprise SSD's.  Things will obviously vary based on your hardware.

  - you need to specify all your hardware that you have in play, the reason for your low transfer speeds might then become obvious.

AND... u mentioned your arch linux server u set up but did not mention what the other *server* was and where you are transferring from/to.  so if that transfer is happening through your router and ISP and over the internet, then that is likely where the choke is.  You need to set up a second server yourself and either connect them directly via a cat5e or cat6 cable or use a simple 1gbps $10 wired switch (not router).